# Is LinkedHashSet best if the frequent operation is both search and insert

Tags: java

Is LinkedHashSet considered to be a best data structure in terms of time complexity/performance when the frequent is insert **and** search?
DoublyLinked is best for insertion and Hashing concept is best for search.

Comment: The advantage of `LinkedHashSet` over a normal `HashSet` is that it preserves the order of insertion. It's not better in any other respect.

Answer (score 1):

Both `LinkedHashSet` and `HashSet` have the same time complexity for both insert (add) and search (contains): O(1).

`LinkedHashSet` is better in that it preserves the order of insertion and also it's next operation upon iteration works in O(1), whereas for `HashSet` it's O(h/n), where h - current capacity of the hash collection, n - number of elements in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

See: http://bigocheatsheet.com/
Hashmap is usually a tiny bit faster as it does not deal with insertion order, but complexity wise they are equal.